# axios equivalent of this curl command

Tags: axios

I'm trying to convert the following curl into an `axios` GET request for use in React Native.

Here's what I want to convert:

```
$ curl --get --user ${client_id}:${client_secret} \
 https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/search \
 --data-urlencode "query=donkey" \
 --data-urlencode "page=2" \
 --data-urlencode "per_page=1"
```

Output of above:

```
{"page":2,"per_page":1,"total_count":42019,"search_id":"g3gruNqeXTnAOggCv9s9hA","data":[{"id":"384331075","aspect":1.1607,"assets":{"preview":{"height":387,"url":"https://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/3969413/384331075/stock-photo-laughing-donkey-good-and-funny-donkey-the-portrait-the-best-photo-of-donkey-in-the-world-384331075.jpg","width":450},"small_thumb":{"height":86,"url":"https://thumb7.shutterstock.com/thumb_small/3969413/384331075/stock-photo-laughing-donkey-good-and-funny-donkey-the-portrait-the-best-photo-of-donkey-in-the-world-384331075.jpg","width":100},"large_thumb":{"height":129,"url":"https://thumb7.shutterstock.com/thumb_large/3969413/384331075/stock-photo-laughing-donkey-good-and-funny-donkey-the-portrait-the-best-photo-of-donkey-in-the-world-384331075.jpg","width":150},"huge_thumb":{"height":260,"url":"https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/laughing-donkey-good-funny-portrait-260nw-384331075.jpg","width":302}},"contributor":{"id":"3969413"},"description":"Laughing donkey - good and funny donkey. The Portrait. The best photo of donkey in the world. Northern Cyprus. Karpasia. Karpaz. Dipkarpaz. Rizokarpaso. Apostolos Andreas cape donkey","image_type":"photo","media_type":"image"}],"spellcheck_info":{}}
```

Here's what I did and it just returns a 401 error:

```
axios.get("https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/search?query=donkey&page=2&per_page=1",{ headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic client_id:client_secret'
    }}).then(res => console.log((res)));
```

Also tried with the following but got a 401 error:

```
axios.get("https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/search?query=donkey&page=1&per_page=1",{ headers: {
  user: client_id:client_secret
}}).then(res => console.log((res)));

axios.get("https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/search?query=donkey&page=1&per_page=1",{ headers: {
  user: client_id, pass: client_secret
}}).then(res => console.log((res)));
```

Should I be converting `client_id:client_key` into a `base64encoded` string?  Also, how can I include the query params in the request without just appending to the URL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out anyway.

```
axios({
      baseURL: 'https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/search?query=donkey&page=1&per_page=1',
      auth: { username: 'CLIENT_ID', password: 'CLIENT_SECRET'},
      params: { query: 'donkey', page: '1', per_page: '1' }  
}).then(res => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score 6):

Paste your curl command into https://curlconverter.com/node-axios/ and it will convert it to

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const response = await axios.get('https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/search', {
    params: {
        'query': 'donkey',
        'page': '2',
        'per_page': '1'
    },
    auth: {
        username: 'client_id',
        password: 'client_secret'
    }
});
```